# Using static method from other file without class name

Tags: c#

I tried to use something like **using Printer;** but it doesn't work.

I just want use *P();* instead of *Printer.P();*

**File Printer.cs**

```
using System;

namespace animals
{
    public class Printer
    {
        public static void P()
        {
            P("\a");
        }

        public static void P(object val, bool doEnterAfterLine = true, bool printInOneLine = false)
        {
            P(val.ToString());
            if (doEnterAfterLine)
                Console.WriteLine(); //enter
        }

        static void P(bool printSeparator = false)
        {
            if (printSeparator == false)
                return;

            P("---------------------------------------------------------", true);
        }


        static void P(string value = "none", bool modifyColor = false, bool ding = false, bool printInOneLine = false)
        {
            var oldColor = Console.ForegroundColor;

            if (modifyColor)
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;

            if (printInOneLine)
                Console.Write(value + " ");
            else
                Console.WriteLine(value);

            Console.ForegroundColor = oldColor; //recover color

            if (ding)
            {
                Console.Write("\a");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**File Program.cs**

```
using System;
// this resolve problem: using static animals.Printer;
 
namespace animals 
{
     class Program
     {
         static void Main(string[] args)
         {           
             Printer.P(); // it works
             P();         // info: does not exist in current context                        
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: you mean `using static animals.Printer.P;`?

Comment: @Omar not `using static animals.Printer;`?

Comment: Probably, I don't remember off the top of my head. [using - static modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#static-modifier)

Comment: Unless you are not showing all the code… the `Printer` class is not valid… `P(“/a”)` … ?

Comment: You should have bigger things to worry about,  however if you look up the documentation to using you will find what you need

Comment: @JohnG 0 I added code, thanks.

Comment: @Llama -you are right, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use `using static <namespace>.<class>;` to access the members of `<class>` without qualifying its name.

```
using static animals.Printer;
```

Comment: Mark this answer as correct by clicking the check mark **if it solved your problem**

Comment: using static animals.Printer; --> work great! Thank you!

Comment: Probably worth adding that I haven't ever seen this used in production code, most likely because it breaks some foundational assumptions about method calls and therefore can cause more problems than the few characters it saves.

Comment: @LukeBriggs I mean, WPF itself has methods like `FindResource()` which you invoke without qualifying its name.